# RadioButtonList OnSelectedIndexChanged event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

On my aspx page I have the following code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdblReasonOption" runat="server"
                                            AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdblReasonOption_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="1" />
                                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And then in my code behind I have:

```
    protected void rdblReasonOption_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnSubmit.Visible = true;
    }
```

However, it never fires and no postback happens. Why is this occurring?

Comment: Does a postback occur?

Comment: Are there any Javascript errors occurring when you select an item? Are you using UpdatePanels?

Comment: Is there any `UpdatePanel` wrapping the content? Did you also added the `ScriptManager`?

Comment: There are no UpdatePanels on the page

Comment: And no javascript errors

Comment: @netorious Please make sure **AutoEventWireup="true"** for page like this `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" ... %>`

Comment: AutoEventWireup is set to true

Comment: One thing worth noting while debugging this issue: When I submit the form, the OnSelectedIndexChanged event fires right before btnSubmitClick event.. although that is too late.

Comment: With just the two markup and code above, Postback happens as verified. Please show your complete markup of .aspx page